# Error: Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors, androidx

I'm Trying to add this https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper But when i add it i get this error "Error: Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl"

I have attached project gradle and app gradle. (i'm new to android development and am not entirely sure how to fix.)

i think it might have something to do with

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
```

But these are used for TextInputLayout in one of my layouts for an activity. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven{
               url  "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

App Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.something.app"
            minSdkVersion 24
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

        ext {
            supportLibVersion = '27.1.1'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
            }

    dependencies {

        api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'



        //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
        // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try to replace `api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'` to `implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use support library whereas new version of `Image-Cropper` Library used `androidx` library.

check [change log](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper#change-log)

So, You have two option either you can move to `androidx` or change library version to old version

`api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'`

Comment: Thank you for this. This solved my problem. I had an issue with the app compat library that needed an older library instead.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my issue by downgrading butterknife dependencies to version 8.8.1

```
// BUTTERKNIFE
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Alternatively, another solution was me for searching through entire project files for any import statements using androidx and then replacing them with the android.support version.

In my case I found -

`import androidx.annotation.NonNull;` which I replaced with `import android.support.annotation.NonNull;`

Answer (score 1):

You can keep latest version and configure `gradle` to use `AndroidX`

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
```

**gradle.properties:**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

From Doc [Using AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/)

> See Migrating to AndroidX to learn how to migrate an existing project.
>
> If you want to use AndroidX in a new project, you need to set the
>   compile SDK to Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher and set both of
>   the following Android Gradle plugin flags to true in your
>   `gradle.properties` file.
>
> `android.useAndroidX`: When set to true, the Android plugin uses the
>   appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library. The flag is
>   false by default if it is not specified.
>
> `android.enableJetifier`: When
>   set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing
>   third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries. The
>   flag is false by default if it is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use
**`api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'`**

Because **`android-image-cropper:2.8.+'`**  is  Update to support library to **AndroidX**

> For **com.android.support** Use this

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
```

> For **AndroidX** Use this

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
```

**Change log 2.8.0**

- Fix crash on Android O
- Update to support library to AndroidX
- Handle failure when selecting non image file
- More translations

For more information Please Read the [**`Change log`**](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper#change-log) of  Android Image Cropper

Answer (score 0):

If you have added a model cropper , remove it
and add

For com.android.support Use this

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
```

For AndroidX Use this

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
```