# Failing on build with androidX error but I am not using androidX in project

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I am trying to build but it gives me errors. I did research and tried following solutions but cant fix.
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/386

[Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

[Error - Android resource linking failed (AAPT2 27.0.3 Daemon #0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0)

[Error: Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095223/error-program-type-already-present-androidx-versionedparcelable-parcelimpl)

Thats the error

```
Error: Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField
```

Thats the screen
[image]

Thats my code

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.30"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this one

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adultgaming.fantasygameapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.30"

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    //Eventbus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Please let me know if I missed something. And if want to devote let me know why.

Comment: It seems that  implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1" is using androidX

Comment: @Shermano it using it but I didnt add it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check inside your gradle.properties, if you have

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Then you do have androidx enabled.

Also, and this may be obvious, but clean your Gradle build with Build -> Clean Project

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**
What is happening is one of your other libraries is using androidx, GLIDE FOR SURE, and maybe others.

**You have two options...**

Easy: Upgrade to androidx... Like why not? Totally worth it.

Hard: Downgrade your dependencies versions to pre androidX versions.

[image: Glide Repo]

Comment: What do you mean cannot compile a .kt with unused resources?

Comment: Ok, I think I figure it out.

Comment: Now all my kotlin classes are corrupted with v7 support library error

Comment: Did you upgrade to androidX?

Comment: Just make sure your project level gradle is updated as follows.

 implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

Comment: And your imports are import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: Yes you were right. The solution is not absolutely for me. But the main idea helped me to find the issue and fix it. Thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197194/discussion-between-richard-dapice-and-boris-ruzanov).

Comment: Im good thank you. I just didnt know that all project suppose to be refactored on imports.